# Google map : How to detect the Event of changing by drag and drop the route displaying by a DirectionRender Service?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google map for a classis case. Here is the code :

```
// create map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), $scope.map_options);
            var dirService= new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var dirRenderer= new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var dirContainer=document.getElementById('dir-container');

             dirRenderer.setOptions({
                 draggable:true,
             });

             var showDirections = function(dirResult, dirStatus) {
            if (dirStatus != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                alert('Veuillez saisir des adresses valides');
                return;
              }
              // Show directions
            dirRenderer.setMap(map);
            dirRenderer.setDirections(dirResult);
            dirRenderer.setPanel(dirContainer);

        };
       dirService.route($scope.master, showDirections);
```

I would like to trigger an event where the user modify the route. Modifying the route is allowed by drag and drop with this option :

```
dirRenderer.setOptions({
                     draggable:true,
                 });
```

How can I catch this event. I've already have this event in my code :

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(dirRenderer, 'routeindex_changed', 
                    function() {  });   
  google.maps.event.addListener(dirRenderer, 'directions_changed', 
                    function() {  });
```

Comment: directions_changed fires when I drag the route (routeindex_changed seems to fire multiple times as well)  http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_directions_changed.html

Comment: Thanks. I thinks is another problem wich make this behaviour, i think i have got it. ( You added twice the event listener to routeIndex_changed). Thanks.

Comment: I added listeners for 2 different events (routeindex_changed and routeInde_changed), the routeIndex_changed one never fires.

Answer (score 2):

its provided in google API directions example.
Following is code to trigger event after drag.

```
       directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
        computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
        console.log(directionsDisplay);
      });
```

Further if you are interested in computeTotalDistance function

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
var total = 0;
var myroute = result.routes[0];
for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
}
total = total / 1000;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
}
```